# What is the Height of the Minimized Application Bar in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm curious of how it would be possible to get the height of the Windows Phone application bar when in 'mini' mode. I've seen several resources on the height when the regular icon buttons are shown, but none with only the ellipses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In codebehind:

```
double appBarMiniSize = ApplicationBar.MiniSize; // 30.0
```

Comment: Thanks, 30px is exactly what I was using from examining the size on the screen, but its nice to have a hard coded way of checking. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you solve this yourself. Create a test app and modify the mainpage to have the following xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="WinPhone8App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
    </Grid>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Minimized">
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="test" />
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Run the application. You'll notice the height will be displayed in the TextBlock. Take that amount and subtract it from 800 and you will have your answer.

Comment: Ok I will certainly test this out. I'm curious though, with the new device sizes in Windows Phone 8 as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx , determining the height of the minimized application bar for 720p and 1080p resolutions would require subtracting by 853 correct?

Comment: It really depends how they (Microsoft) implement this. Currently the height of the page is always "800" and then scaled up to fit the screen. So for a 920 device that has a resolution of 1280x768, it still says the ActualHeight is 800 for the entire page. I'm hoping this changes as I'd like to put more content on larger devices, not the same amount of content which is just bigger.