# What is the Height of th Minimized Application Bar

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

For Windows Phone, I know the height of the standard application bar is 72 pixels, but what about the minimized application bar? How might I find this out?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507349/what-is-the-height-of-the-minimized-application-bar-in-windows-phone

Comment: Forgot I asked that question earlier. When following the example, I got 62 as the minimized app bar height. How can this be, when the regular height is 72 and look so much bigger than the minimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In codebehind:

```
double appBarMiniSize = ApplicationBar.MiniSize; // 30.0
```